# Change font size of all elements inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following page in which there is a div menu. Inside menu we can have `<table>`, `<p>`, `<h>`. Different elements for example:

```
<div id="menu">
 <p>abc def</p>
 <table>
  <tr><td>helloo </td><tr>
  <tr><td>hiii </td><tr>
 </table>
 <div id="sub"><p>123 this is test</p></div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to change size of all text in between elements inside menu. For example: abc def, hellooo, hiii, 123 this is test. Can i change all that text using jquery or javascript some how.

Comment: #menu { font-size: 14px; } #sub { font-size: 12px; }

Comment: I've given an example of jQuery/JS below, but now we need to know 'when' this is happening. Because if it's page load, you should just use the CSS doc because it needs less processing. If it's an 'event' then when is the event take place?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this with css:

```
#menu {
   font-size: XXX;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Yes you can use JavaScript and or jQuery to do what you want, but why wouldn't you just use CSS like suggested?

or you can try this:

```
<Style>
    /*Assumed everything is inheriting font-size*/
    #menu{
      font:12px;
    }
    /* Force all children to have a specified font-size */
    #menu *{
      font:14px;
    }
</style>

<script>
    //JavaScript
    document.getElementById('menu').style.fontSize = "14px";
    //jQuery
    $("#menu").css({'font-size':'14px'});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery Example

```
$('#menu').nextAll().css('font', '14px');
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/jdw6K/

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  var VINCI = {};

 VINCI.Page = {

init : function() {
    this.initFontResize();
},

initFontResize : function() {
    var container = $('#menu, #sub');
    var originalFontSize = parseFloat(container.css('font-size'), 10);

    var size_level = 0;
    var maximum_size_level = 5;
    var size_change_step = 1.4;

    function calculateFontSize()
    {
        return originalFontSize + (size_level * size_change_step);
    }

      // Increase Font Size
      $('.increaseFont').click(function(){
        if (size_level < maximum_size_level) {
           size_level++;
           container.stop().animate({'font-size' : calculateFontSize()});
        }
        return false;
      });

      // Decrease Font Size
    $('.decreaseFont').click(function(){
          if (size_level > 0) {
           size_level--;
           container.stop().animate({'font-size' : calculateFontSize()});
        }
        return false;
    });

 };

VINCI.Page.init();
```